# Creating a new column which contains strings from before the second occurrence of a % symbol

Tags: r

I have some character string and I would like to use `str_split` or `separate` in order to split some of the observations.

The data looks like:

```
                                              string
1                                          timdevine
2                                       javierestaun
3         mar%C3%A7al-saur%C3%AD-g%C3%B3mez-a3a5bb10
4                                              eladi
5                                               <NA>
6  pablo-jos%C3%A9-mart%C3%ADn-garc%C3%ADa-1719b5153
7                                               <NA>
8                                            dvdmena
9                                               <NA>
10                      g%C3%B6khan-baykal-288548187
```

I would like to split the rows by the second occurrence of the `%` symbol where I extract the text before it.

Expected output:

```
                                              string       slitString
1                                          timdevine           NA
2                                       javierestaun           NA
3         mar%C3%A7al-saur%C3%AD-g%C3%B3mez-a3a5bb10           mar%C3    # since this is before the second %
4                                              eladi           NA
5                                               <NA>           NA
6  pablo-jos%C3%A9-mart%C3%ADn-garc%C3%ADa-1719b5153           pablo-jos%C3
7                                               <NA>           NA
8                                            dvdmena           NA
9                                               <NA>           NA
10                      g%C3%B6khan-baykal-288548187           g%C3
```

Data:

```
    df <- structure(list(string = c("timdevine", "javierestaun", "mar%C3%A7al-saur%C3%AD-g%C3%B3mez-a3a5bb10", 
"eladi", NA, "pablo-jos%C3%A9-mart%C3%ADn-garc%C3%ADa-1719b5153", 
NA, "dvdmena", NA, "g%C3%B6khan-baykal-288548187")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively,

```r
stringr::str_extract(df$string, "^[^%]+%[^%]+(?=%)")
#  [1] NA             NA             "mar%C3"       NA             NA            
#  [6] "pablo-jos%C3" NA             NA             NA             "g%C3"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on `str_split()`:

```
purrr::map_chr(
  str_split(df$string, '%'), ~if (length(.) > 2) str_c(.[1:2], collapse = '%') else NA
)
```

Comment: This is a nice solution to avoid regular expressions, and handles cases of less `%`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sub`:

```
sub("(.*?%.*?)%.*|.*", "\\1", df$string)
# [1] ""             ""             "mar%C3"       ""             NA            
# [6] "pablo-jos%C3" NA             ""             NA             "g%C3"
```